# Tip on jQuery school schedule builder plugin/code?

Tags: jquery

Im thinking of building a drag and drop schedule builder to create schedules for schools with jQuery.
Anybody that has any good tip if there is any good ones out there already? Thanks!

Comment: You can use the javascript tool JsPlumb for doing this ... Best of Luck

Comment: [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) might help